# Salesforce Marketing Cloud ability to drop files to different child BU's FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp

I have 2 ftp

Root BU

and NL BU

In root BU ,i have automation where i get main data . I work on the data , and then segment NL data . I need to drop the NL data to NL's BU FTP

Question:
1. Is it possible to drop a file in child BU's FTP 
2. How to do it

Comment: Have at look at the answer here. It's not exactly what you are looking for but may help in achieving your goal. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143924/activating-multiple-triggered-automations-across-business-units/143964 

OR you can use jitterbit to query data from parent BU and put it in Child BU FTP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

based on checking with salesforce , it seems that our port where not whitelisted . Thus the problem. However i was surprise when tier 1 mentioned that you cannot drop a file to child bu. Tier 2 told me the error is due to not whitelisting some ports

Comment: Is the data you are looking to send to child inside of a DE (after your filtering, etc) that you need to export or is it already on the FTP?

Comment: As the accepted answer, can you clarify if the solution is that SFMC has told you that A) with your current set up it is not possible, or B) if you just needed to Whitelist some ports and my above solution was able to work? If B, please pull in a summation of my proposed solution so it is easy reference for anyone with the similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

You would want to add the SFTP information for your child unit into your Parent BU as a 'File Location'. This can be found in the admin section under Data Management. This would require you to choose the location type of 'external SFTP site'.  From there you type in the full FTP path of your child BU's SFTP as well as the corresponding Username and password.

You would then perform the data extract as you normally would. The file transfer you use to place it on the SFTP would then use the new 'Destination' you created via 'File Location'. This will place it into the specific folder on the Child BUs SFTP.

You can also have it stored inside of a Shared DE via the Parent BU if you just need a Data Extension to reference for the Child BU and don't need the actual file saved to the SFTP.

Comment: Dear Gortonington  .  Shared DE is not preferred due to security reason. On the SFTP solution, I was doing exactly what you are suggesting ( don't know how to post a screenshot in the window) . ...I get an error as internal error has occured and please contact system admin

Comment: can you give me more info on the error? Which part gave  you the error?

Comment: Dear Gortonington   ...i get this error --> ERROR:  An undefined error occurred. Contact your account representative if the error persists.. The error comes from the file transfer part

Comment: Verify the ftp info us correct. Sounds like that is issue.

Comment: based on checking with salesforce , it seems that our port where not whitelisted . Thus the problem. However i was surprise when tier 1 mentioned that you cannot drop a file to child bu. Tier 2 told me the error is due to not whitelisting some ports